# how to override vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ImageUploader.php in my custom module and magento showing error "Code Duplicates Detected"

Tags: new-products

> File: `brijeshjp2006/sliders/brijeshjp2006-sliders-1.0.5.0/Model/ImageUploader.php`
>   Line: 2
>   File: `magento/module-catalog/magento-module-catalog-102.0.3.0/Model/ImageUploader.php`
>   Line: 6

Comment: Please don't just dump error messages in the question form. You should at least explain
when it happens and if you did any changes before. To debug errors, follow this guide:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 3):

Do not just copy the entire file from the core files- here what you need to do is to extend your class form core file and put the methods in your class in which you have made any changes; otherwise it should work fine.

```
class ImageUploader extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, I have done same. now the module is in technical round. when the error will resolve then I return my feedback

Comment: Error still showing from magento tester after extend like this = class ImageUploader extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader

Comment: Also Need change name of variables.